# Inscribe and center an image within a frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a div of arbitrary aspect ratio, what's the best way to place and style an image (also with an arbitrary aspect ratio) inside such that:

1. It is both inscribed and centered
2. Its dimensions and position are set using relative values so that the image will remain inscribed and centered automatically when the frame is uniformly scaled (javascript should only be required when the image is initially inserted, or if the frame's aspect ratio changes)
3. Extra markup is minimized

Here's the result we want:

[image: example of inscribe and centered]

[Here's a fiddle template](http://jsfiddle.net/PBPkh/), which is just:

Markup

```
Should pillarbox
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/300" />
</div>

Should letterbox
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/300/200" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.frame {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 0px 100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining [Adrift's css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23812907/470472)

```
.frame {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 0px 100px 0;
    position: relative; /* added */
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

with javascript

```
var inscribe = function(img, frame) {
    var imgRatio = img.width / img.height;
    var frameRatio = frame.offsetWidth / frame.offsetHeight;

    if (imgRatio > frameRatio) { // image is wider than frame; letterbox
        img.style.width = '100%';
        img.style.height = 'auto';
    } else {                     // image is taller than frame; pillarbox
        img.style.width = 'auto';
        img.style.height = '100%';
    }
}
```

all requirements can be satisfied.

http://jsfiddle.net/PBPkh/4/

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBPkh/2/)

```
.frame {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 0px 100px 0;
    position: relative; /* added */
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really close, but fails when the frame is larger than the image. See http://jsfiddle.net/PBPkh/3/.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can achieve that with background-images too, if you can get rid of the `<img />` elements.

There is a css property on ***background-size*** called ***contain***, that does the job:

```
.background{
   background-size: contain;
}
```

And if you wish to center the image just add this:

```
background-position: center center;
```